# Liquibase precondition-sql-check is completely ignored

Tags: liquibase, preconditions

I am trying to make my legacy SQL code compatible with Liquibase. As for now I use Liquibase 4.23.
I stumbled upon an issue when precondition-sql-check is completely ignored no matter which query I use. To play around with it I just took an example from [Liquibase docs](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/preconditions.html).

liquibase.properties:

```
e1d3120ee6eb:~$ cat liquibase.properties 

url: jdbc:mysql://liquibase-check-stream-mysql/stream
username: root
password: ...
showBanner: false
changelogFile: ./changesets/example.sql
```

example.sql:

```
e1d3120ee6eb:~$ cat changesets/example.sql 
-- liquibase formatted sql
            
-- changeset Liquibase User:1
-- preconditions onFail:WARN 
-- precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example_table
-- comment: /* Comments should go after the precondition. Otherwise, Liquibase returns an error. */
create table example_table (  
    id int primary key,
    firstname varchar(50),
    lastname varchar(50) not null,
    state char(2)
)
```

I run empty mysql:8 container and create this `example_table`:

```
podman exec -it liquibase-check-stream-mysql mysql -p... stream
mysql> create table example_table (  
    -> id int primary key,
    -> firstname varchar(50),
    -> lastname varchar(50) not null,
    -> state char(2)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_stream |
+------------------+
| example_table    |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I run `liquibase update`:

```
e1d3120ee6eb:~$ liquibase update
Starting Liquibase at 23:56:40 (version 4.23.0 #10709 built at 2023-06-23 21:18+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.23.0
Liquibase Open Source 4.23.0 by Liquibase
Running Changeset: changesets/example.sql::1::Liquibase User

Unexpected error running Liquibase: Migration failed for changeset changesets/example.sql::1::Liquibase User:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'example_table' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) create table example_table (  
    id int primary key,
    firstname varchar(50),
    lastname varchar(50) not null,
    state char(2)
)]
```

I tried different values for `onFail` attribute and different queries for `--precondition-sql-check`. I also used rubbish queries to see if MySQL at least runs them to check the precondition. It looks like no query has ever been run by Liquibase.

I also ran `liquibase update --log-level=debug`, bug can't see any messages regarding preconditions.

Could you please point me on what am I doing wrong?